# Create an index with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'return':[10, 28, 32, 50, 25]})
```

I want to set 25 (last element) to be 100 in a new column and then work backwards doing 50*100/25=200, 32*100/25=32*200/50=128..and so on

```
   return index
0      25  
1      28   
2      32   128
3      50   200
4      25   100
```

Is there any way of doing this in -preferably- one line. Thanks!

```
df['index']=.... ???
```

Comment: `df['index'] = df['return'] * 4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) to extract the last value of a series:

```
df['index'] = df['return'] * 100 / df['return'].iat[-1]

print(df)

   return  index
0      10   40.0
1      28  112.0
2      32  128.0
3      50  200.0
4      25  100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible with **One** line. Just use `df['return'].iloc[-1]` to get the last value of the `return` column and then simple do like below-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'return':[10, 28, 32, 50, 25]})
df['index'] = (df['return'] * 100  / df['return'].iloc[-1]).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       return  index
0      10     40
1      28    112
2      32    128
3      50    200
4      25    100
```

Comment: In the *general* case you likely don't want to convert to `int`. Just here we have an `int` factor because 25 is a divisor of 100.

Comment: @jpp agreed sir, I just follow the OP's expected output that's why converted to `int`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'return':[10, 28, 32, 50, 25]})

last = df["return"].iloc[-1] 
df['index'] = df['return'].apply(lambda x: x*(100/last))

df
```

It gives:

```
    return  index
0   10  40.0
1   28  112.0
2   32  128.0
3   50  200.0
4   25  100.0
```

Comment: This would be good if instead of hardcoding 25 you would do `last = df["return"].iloc[-1]` and then `df['index'] = df['return'].apply(lambda x: x*(100/last))
`

Comment: Question: using lambda functions is the same as vectorizing the code? Or does it take as much time as a for loop through all the values?

Comment: @Oniropolo No, it's the opposite.

Comment: If possible don't use apply() with lambda functions. It's slower than vectorized operations.